# Need to change timezone dynamically for existing project

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, timezone

There is an existing project only for one country. But for now, it should be used for multiple countries. So I need some place to change timezones. I decided to update & insert in only London/Sydney timezone. I need to change the timezone for all select queries. I just tried with middlewares, but I could not achieve it. Please give your suggestions.

Linux server, MySQL, Laravel, Vagrant

```
namespace App\Http\v2018_06_12\Middleware;

use App;
use App\Order;
use Closure;

class LocaleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $locale = ($request->hasHeader('locale')) ? $request->header('locale') : 'uk';

        $timezone = env('APP_TIMEZONE');

        if ('aus' == $locale) {
            $timezone = 'Australia/Sydney';
        }
        config(['app.timezone' => $timezone]);
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

        print_r(Order::select('delivery_time')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first()->toArray());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Need to change timezone"* - what do you mean? Change in the database according from where user is from? Show some data with time formatted?

Comment: A good point to start from is to save timestamps with timezone in the database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Australia has more timezones than just the Sydney one. I would strongly recommend you store everything on the serverside in UTC and then format the presentation on the clientside using JavaScript which has access to the real timezone/locale settings of the user.